# asking mysql to index full-text at a faster rate

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

with mysql fulltext search i have disabled stop words using the method

```
ft_stopword_file = ""
ft_min_word_len = 1
```

and then i dropped the full text indexes and re-created them.

Now the real problem, there are around 500K rows which needs to indexed for full-text.

When i search for "java" with query -

```
select job_id from job_posts where match(description) 
against ('+"java"' in boolean mode) order by job_id desc limit 10;
```

it comes up with -

```
10 rows in set (41.73 sec)
```

for the 42 seconds the CPU was at around 15-25%

When i search for "with", the query -

```
 select job_id from job_posts where match(description) 
 against ('+"with"' in boolean mode) order by job_id desc limit 10;
```

it comes up with -

```
10 rows in set (3 min 22.04 sec)
```

again for 3.3 mins the cpu was at 15-25%

Why with "java" it takes just 20% of time as compared to "with" as both are 4 letter words?

I see without any queries mysql is idling out at around <2% cpu which means it is indexing but at a very slow rate.

Is there any way to ask or set mysql to index at a higher rate using ~50% cpu and disk?

Just in case for real-time queries you can search for strings [here](https://jobs.nvoids.com)

The create statement for the table -

```
CREATE TABLE `job_posts` (
  `job_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci,
  `state` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `msg_no` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_hotlist` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `cviews` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `em_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`),
  KEY `id_email` (`em_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `full_text` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: Can you please also add SHOW CREATE TABLE output to your question?

Comment: `ft_stop_word_file` and `ft_min_word_len` are used for `MyISAM` fulltext indexes - but your table is a `InnoDB` table. -> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#ft_min_word_len

Comment: well they were at the default earlier and 2 words(no / so) and skip words ('with' / 'www') were not searchable. My case is with mysql 8.0.34

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya How long does it take to search for Adam?  Again a 4 letter word.

Comment: adam took 0.02 seconds @WilsonHauck the number of rows were only 560

Comment: My suspicion is you are seeing evidence of Adam is quick, Java is slower and with takes the longest.  One reason, A is the first letter of the search, J is the 10 letter and W is the 23rd letter of the alphabet.  You have to reach deeper into the index for with than for Adam.   Your use of - ft_min_word_len = 1 - rather than using 3 also causes more entries in the index to search through. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: maybe most probably it's related to the number of rows, "zen" took 0.04 seconds, the number of rows were 72 @WilsonHauck